# django: how to detect whether page loading is no longer relevant?

Tags: django, performance

I have a site where it takes a few seconds to generate a page, due to having a crappy server. People visiting it will spam the refresh button. The problem is that the threads that are already loading the page don't stop, so you end up having 2-3 things generating the same page, all but one being discarded. Is there any way to check whether a page load is no longer necessary so I can abort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that i'm aware of even if you could detect from the users browser I don't think apache can be notified and even if it could interrupting a running django thread isn't that easy a solution. Have you looked into caching your pages? Should give you the most performance improvement ESP. If generating pages is your bottleneck.